# Adding code that contains CDATA doesn't format correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, code-formatting

When adding a code sample if it contains // < ![CDATA[ (without spaces) it will not display correctly, anything after // will not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
 // <![CDATA[<sender>John Smith</sender>]]> more stuff here
 some code
 some more code
 even more code
 enough already with the code!
```

Seems fine to me.. did you indent 4 spaces as specified in the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help ?

Comment: that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Because it's treating < as the start of a HTML tag (I had a similar problem). Print it as `&lt;` and you'll be fine.